# MySQL Innodb Deadlock - how to remove old event?

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock, alarm, zenoss

My monitoring tool, Zenoss, is reporting a 'LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK' event from a MySQL Innodb engine. 
When I run 'show engine innodb status\G' I get the following information about the deadlock:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
130819 14:01:12
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 0 108626388, ACTIVE 0 sec, process no 8726, OS thread id 47220783470912
starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 4 lock struct(s), heap size 1216, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 4283, query id 21974219 10.92.210.108 ddrsrbe Updating
update ddrsproduction.requests set request_priority_grade_id=3, costs=0, data_version=1, date_completed='2013-08-19 13:59:39', date_end='2013-05-24 23:59:00', date_required_by='2013-08-26 13:57:31', date_start='2013-05-19 00:01:00', date_submitted='2013-08-19 13:57:31', designated_authority_id=84528, is_manual=1, missed_sla_reason=null, missed_sla_reason_ask_user=null, product_id=35, request_cost_status_id=0, request_delivery_method_id=0, request_legislation_id=0, request_method_id=0, request_reason_id=1, request_result_status_id=null, origin_id=0, request_status_id=2, request_type_id=1, result_row_count=2, results_last_downloaded=null, site_processed='KNOW', time_zone=null, urn='LBP/281/35/12 (CONS)', user_id=2357, vf_rep_id=8 where request_id=132536
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
```

You can see that the deadlock was in August last year, and I cannot kill the thread as it no longer exists:

```
mysql> kill 4283;
ERROR 1094 (HY000): Unknown thread id: 4283
```

I am getting bored receiving this event in to Zenoss, and would very much like to purge the innodb engine of this alarm.
I have Googled high and low for an answer and have come up with zilch, nada, nothing.
Any help hugely appreciated :-)

Comment: Have you tried `kill query 21974219`?

Comment: mysql> kill query 21974219;
    ERROR 1094 (HY000): Unknown thread id: 21974219
:(

Comment: AND the other id? 47220783470912

Comment: The same I'm afraid:
mysql> kill query 47220783470912;
ERROR 1094 (HY000): Unknown thread id: 47220783470912

Comment: What if you run the update statement in the lock? See if it creates a new lock and maybe you can kill that one

Comment: Hmmm, will have to check if I'm allowed to re-run that update command. In the meantime, is the suggestion here that this deadlock still exists? If it does, why on earth won't these kill commands work?

Comment: I cannot imagine, but since its still in the engine innodb status its strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to clear the `LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK` section in `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` unfortunately. The query has already been killed by the deadlock detector, so there's nothing you can `KILL`. The only way to reset that information is to restart the server.

No properly written software should continuously alert due to the presence of something in that output.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` to get the list of all connections and kill the connection performing the update, or all inactive/sleeping sessions using Kill command if no update shows up.

Comment: Thanks for this @cedric-simon. The very top ID in the resulting list is for user _system user_ with a command of _Connect_ and a time value of _14690265_! State says **Waiting for master to send event**. Is that normal?

Comment: Looks like a replication status. Do you use replication? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-administration-status.html